# Server Bandwidth monitoring Windows Server 2012 (with historic data)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, monitoring

I have a requirement to monitor the amount of bandwidth used on a Windows 2012 Server with historic data of what application has used the bandwidth (not just the bandwidth used). This is required because the datacentre is saying our server is using a lot of bandwidth and supplied graphs, but I need to both verify this is correct (assume so) and establish which application is using all this data. Graphs supplied show massive spikes lasting a whole day in duration (the days seem to be random, but once or twice a week, so impossible to monitor constantly, hence the need to be able to get historic data going back up to a month.

Any suggestions for software which may be able to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your datacenter guys should also be able to tell you what application is using the most bandwidth using one of the flow protocols (netflow, jflow, sflow or ipfix).

If they can't or won't tell you, then you could try a packet sniffer running directly on that Win2012 server:  wireshark is the gold standard here, but it gives live data, not historic data, so you'll need to run it as the problem is happening. Alternatively, you could try the free version of PRTG and the "packet sniffer" sensor, which is more work for you to set up but which records historical data.